# Email-to-activity processing – create Activity at future date

Tags: civimail, email, activity, scheduled-follow-up

I would like to be able to set tasks on a Contact using the Email-to-Activity processor. This would allow me to set Scheduled activities on a Contact in CiviCRM, like:

Follow-up with Sally in two weeks about the topic of the email I'm sending right now

Is there a way to do this?

Example:

I'm emailing a Contact from gmail and in the BCC field I add my Email-to-activity address to attach the email to the Contact's record in CiviCRM.

I would also like to add another Email-to-activity processor address like 2-week-follow-up@my-org.com that would:

1. Add an Activity to the Contact with a Type I specify (email, phone, etc)
2. Sets the date to a future date I determine (ie. two weeks from today)
3. Sets the Activity Status to "scheduled"

This would replicate the functionality of Highrise Task Dropboxes: https://help.highrisehq.com/email/task-dropboxes/

Comment: Sounds entirely do-able via an Extension - if you don't get help here (assuming you want to do this yourself) then perhaps hop on chat in the dev room - or dev-newcomers

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) for this. Every time an incoming email activity is created in CiviCRM civirules could create a follow up activity in the future.

You need to configure CiviRules in such a way that the trigger is "activity is added", and that you have a condition on the incoming email activity type. And the the action is "create an activity" which is the "follow up activity".

Also note that civiRules triggers for each contact involved in an activity. The latter could be filtered out by a condition provided by civirules.

Documentation of civirules could be found at: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Comment: To add a few links to Jaap's suggestion (which I second wholeheartedly :-)): CiviRules can be found at https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules  and documentation on CiviRules at https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Comment: Very helpful! I've been poking around Civirules, but this might be a great practical use case to get me started.

Now, I don't want the follow-up activity to be added to every incoming email.   Is there a way to differentiate the incoming email processing into two types, only one of which triggers the Civirules rules?

Comment: You can probably do this in CiviRules by adding a condition, how do you differentiatie between the two?

Comment: Good idea. I could differentiate by having some standard triggering text within the Activity.

ie. OPERATOR = Contains the text
TEXT TO MATCH = I will remind you

Should the text to match be enclosed in quotations if I want an exact match? ie. "I will remind you" ?

Comment: I would say try out whether the text should be between quotes or not. I dont know exactly.